# Simple Data Caching using Weak References in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, weak-references

Given that I have the following WCF service:

```
class LookUpService
{
   public List<County> GetCounties(string state)
   {
       var db = new LookUpRepository();
       return db.GetCounties(state);
   }
}

class County
{
    public string StateCode{get;set;}
    public string CountyName{get;set;}
    public int CountyCode{get;set;}
}
```

What will be the most efficient (or best) way to cache a state's counties using weak references (or any other approach) so that we don't hit the database every time we need to look up data.

**Note** that we will not have access to the HttpRuntime (and HttpContext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you're going to want to use a `WeakReference` style hash table of sorts.  None is available in the BCL (until 4.0) but there are several available online.  I will be using the following for this sample

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/03/03/building-a-weakreference-hashtable.aspx

Try the following cdoe

```
class LookupService {
  private WeakHashtable<string,List<Count>> _map = new WeakHashtable<string,List<County>>();
  public List<County> GetCounties(string state) {
    List<Count> found;
    if ( !_map.TryGetValue(state, out found)) { 
      var db = new LookUpRepository();
      found = db.GetCounties(state);
      _map.Add(state,found);
    }
    return found;
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's not much different than using a normal `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not have acccess to HttpRuntime?  You don't need the context.  You only need the class.

You can [use System.Web.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(VS.80).aspx) in a non-ASP.NET app, without using the HttpContext.

see also [Caching in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922116/caching-in-wcf/922194#922194)