# How to implement caching in WCF services?

Tags: .net, wcf

How to implement caching in WCF services?

Comment: The question is waay too generic. What kind of service do you have? what are you trying to cache?

Answer (score 2):

Check links below. Can be useful

http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/08/10/architecture-wcf-services-and-caching.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31656584/caching-data-for-a-wcf-service.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFCache.aspx

Similar question was asked here

[Caching in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922116/caching-in-wcf)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

this is a good article:
http://cascadeofinsights.com/post/1410736927/introducing-attribute-based-caching

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Server Appfabric Cache V1.0