# how to use data cache in WCF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, caching

My case is use WCF to return datatable from sqlserver database.
some wcf method use in high frequency. so it will give much more stress to database.
can we use cache in wcf,like http cache,set a expire time. in expire time ,return cached datatable,out expire time ,select the data from sqlserver again.
thx, i'm the first time to use stackoverflow ,and I'm from china,sorry for my poor english.
ps: my wcf case use winform/console as host,not iis.

Comment: try using System.Caching, very easy to use. Also, if you want you can look into some of the persistent caching libraries like escent.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or later, you can use the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class.  For example:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

You can store your `DataSet` in the cache with a line like this:

```
cache["MyDataSet"] = myDataSet; // myDataSet is your DataSet
```

You can then use the following logic to retrieve the `DataSet`:

```
if (cache["MyDataSet"] != null)
{
    // Get your DataSet from the database
}
else
{
    myDataSet = (DataSet)cache["MyDataSet"];
}
```

Also, take a look at [CacheItemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx), which will allow you to set eviction and expiration policies for a given item in the cache.

Comment: thx,I find that method later,like your post.It's hard to decide which wcf method use cache ,and some other sync problem.if there is any way to retrive database change,if has change then select again, else use cache,then no sync problem.Hope can find a way to hash a table in sqlserver to find if table has changed.

Comment: Take a look at [SqlChangeMonitor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor.aspx) for one way to monitor changes to the underlying SQL.  You'll probably need to monitor a table and/or columns, not the DataSet itself (similar to SqlCacheDepdency).

Comment: See this example [.NET 4.0 MemoryCache with SqlChangeMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167282/NET-4-0-MemoryCache-with-SqlChangeMonitor) for one way to do this (MSDN is a little light on how to use it).

Comment: On your first line of code, I get a compilation error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache' to 'venuefinder.controls.ObjectCache'" :(

Comment: @NickG - What is `venuefinder.controls.ObjectCache`?  You'll get more help if you post a question and give relevant code/information.

Comment: @Tim You've made me realise what the problem is! For some reason, another developer created a totally empty class called "ObjectCache" within my project (about 2 years ago according to source control). I hadn't realised the significance of own projects namespace in the error. No idea why that class is there as it's empty. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this meet your needs? This is pseudo code, but I think it gets the point across.

```
static DataTable dt;
static DateTime LastPulled;

public static void GetData()
    {
    if(LastPulled==null || DateTime.Now-LastPulled > new TimeSpan(5))
        {
        //Retrieve DataTable from database
        }
     return dt;
    }
```

Also, see [Caching in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922116/caching-in-wcf)

Comment: use this can work,but it's too redundant,is there a common class to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you need one, it would be pretty simple to make yourself. I would use a delegate so that you can specify the action for your class to perform to update the data.

Comment: Try looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx for existing classes.